# SQL function not working properly, but does when not as a function

Tags: sql, sql-server, function

I'm having another issue with a SQL Function that I had written. If I run it not in a function and use declared variables, then it works perfectly. But as soon as I put it into a function and run it, nothing appears, its empty.

I cannot put this into a stored procedure, it needs to be in a function.

the code is

```
select * from [MYTABLE]
where MajorGroupID = @MajorGroupID
and ((@Status = 0 and (
Inactive = 0)
))
or MajorGroupID = @MajorGroupID and (@Status = 1 and (Inactive = 0 or Inactive = 1))
```

I am not really familiar with functions, I can do basic things with functions but when it comes to adding logic to it. If I was allowed to use stored procedures then I wouldn't be having problems.

This is MSSQL and using SQL Server 2010.

> **EDIT, Added complete function**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[WT_FN_GET_MYTABLE_By_MajorGroupID_Inactive]
(
@MajorGroupID varchar,
@Status int
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN

select * from [MYTABLE]
where MajorGroupID = @MajorGroupID
and ((@Status = 0 and (
Inactive = 0)
))
or MajorGroupID = @MajorGroupID and (@Status = 1 and (Inactive = 0 or Inactive = 1))
```

Comment: So the code to create the function would have been handy wouldn't it? What you are looking for is a table value function. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191165(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: @GSerg, This is actually supposed to be a Table Valued function...I'll post the entire function..

Comment: You don't provide a length for the varchar, so it is going to be `1` and will truncate.

Comment: @GSerg, after I made the change then it worked. Please post as answer so I can accept it

Comment: Err, SQL Server 2010, by the way? I must have missed that version somehow :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't provide a length for `@MajorGroupID varchar`, so it is going to be `1` by default, at which point it will not find anything in the table.

Provide a length, e.g. `@MajorGroupID varchar(30)`.